# How to read QR code in android studio and save the result

Tags: android

i am at beginner level in android. i want to develop an app which scan QR code using camera and shows the result of QR code. There are many solution there but every time i try code the error appear or exception is there. i want complete step by step process in android studio or tutorial link

Comment: You can't read QR in Android Studio - it's IDE. Although, you can write a plugin for everything...

Comment: Seriously though. Please show us what you tried so far.

Comment: I follow the Scanning and generating barcodes using ZXING library on Android
i follow each and every step but at the end the app built and close like exception is there

Comment: I want simple code that i can use in my app to decode QR code which is on my card. i am tiring since last two week 
i found eclipse tutorial or solution not for android studio

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend you to check Udacity, they have awesome [free courses for beginners](https://www.udacity.com/course/android-development-for-beginners--ud837) and intermediate developers. Also they have Android Developer [Nanodegree](https://www.udacity.com/course/android-developer-nanodegree--nd801) and one of it's projects is to create a Barcode scanner app, which is very similar to scanning QR code.

Also you could try using library like [this](https://github.com/zxing/zxing) to implement QR-scanner functionality, but using library won't improve your knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ZXing library for reading the bar-codes and parsing the contents. Here's a good tutorial. 
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-create-a-barcode-reader--mobile-17162

Comment: I follow step by step this 
it shows 
this aap requires barcode sccaner would you like to INSTALL it.


also in logcat
598-598/com.example.mabdullah.qrcodetestfriday E/Trace﹕ error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)